# Fullcalendar onmouseover display a different template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, mouseover

Currently using Full calendar (http://fullcalendar.io/download/) with Angular (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar)

[image]

Is it possible to inject a new html template on mouseover on each day so it displays the edit/view template as below?

I notice there's a mouse over for the events but not easy for me to do a mouseover for the day.

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on fullcalendar.js after line 4810

I have have manually add this event.

```
        $(node).mouseenter(function() {
            view.trigger('dayMouseenter', null, date, $(node));
        });
```